# How to command a 220v device through a 12v output

Tags: relay

I have a vending control board whose output is 12v-DC but the problem is that with this device I have to control a device whose input is 220V-AC. Can anybody help me make this possible? Sorry for my dumb question but i am relatively new to electronics.

Comment: Like....A relay?

Comment: A relay should work. Pick one with the right characteristics.

Comment: That would depend on  your definition of "control"....

Comment: More info required to properly answer this....

Answer (score 1):

Relays are commonly used for this type of application. These are available for panel mount or as PCB modules for incorporation into a project case or machine cabinet.

[image]

*Figure 1. Industrial relay and panel or DIN mount base.*

[image]

*Figure 2. PCB relay on board.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foz0su.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. The schematic symbol is(?) self explanatory. The coil pulls the contact closed when energised.*

- Pick the relay mechanical packaging to suit your application.
- Choose one with a 12 V DC coil.
- Choose one with contact current ratings greater or equal to your load current.

Comment: What type of **application?** "*i have to control a device*" does not necessarily mean turn on and off.. Even if it does, a relay may not be the right solution if ne needs it turned on and off 30 times a second. Question is unclear.

Comment: Agreed. This advice is worth no more than he paid for it.

Comment: Nice complete answer to the simple app though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use something called a *relay*.  These are basically electrically-controlled mechanical switches.

The input side is a electro-magnet.  When the magnet is activated, it causes something to move, which changes the state of a mechanical switch.

12 V is a very common relay coil voltage.  You can easily find relays that can switch several Amps at 220 VAC, and that are controlled with 12 VDC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to electronics and looking for a solution with parts already picked for you, check out the PowerSwitchTail for 200-240VAC: http://www.powerswitchtail.com/240vac-kits

I have used their 110VAC module, which comes with the plugs already attached, in my own home. Their 220VAC versions look like you must add the plugs yourself, but that actually offers much needed flexibility for your application, seeing as how 220VAC supplies differ in their connections. Also Google for guides to set these up - many people have used them in home automation projects.